# Leksah system scope module browser is empty

Tags: browser, haskell, module, windows-xp, leksah

I have just installed leksah following the [user manual](http://leksah.org/leksah_manual.pdf). The manual says that I should do a ghc-pkg recache before starting Leksah for the first time, or I might see an empty module browser at the system scope. My problem is that this is what I am seeing, even though I did the recache.

Basically, my setup process was this: Leksah install -> ghc-pkg recache -> starting Leksah. Then I get to a screen which tells me that Leksah will collect and download metadata for my installed packages, and warns me that it might take long time. Using the recommended defaults there, I see a progress bar for about five seconds, and then Leksah starts. These defaults were:

- No paths for haskell package sources.
- Prebuild metadata URL: http://www.leksah.org.
- Retrieve, then build.
- Server port: 11111.
- End server with last connection.

Reading on in the manual, it says that the location of haskell package sources could be omitted (which was the default), if I just wanted to test, and the location could be filled in later. This leads me to believe that the missing Haskell source paths are the problem, but then I don´t know where my haskell sources are. They don´t seem to be in the Haskell Platform folder. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Other stuff, which might help:

- I have grep on my path as well as wget, as specified in the manual.
- The ghc-pkg recache command takes about a second. I don´t know, if it should be more.
- Doing a Rebuild Metadata, I get a console with a lot of numbers from 0 to 1 for update_toolbar, and then a lot of "starting server" -> "metadata collector has nothing to do" -> "metadata collection has finished".

my setup:

- win xp sp3
- ghc 6.12.3
- Leksah 0.8.0.6
- GNU grep 2.5.4
- GNU wget 1.5.3.1

I´ll be happy to provide more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the preferences under metadata you need to put the path to package sources in the section "Paths under which Haskell source for package maybe found", they should be under your home path in .cabal directory. For me this was "/home/korcan/.cabal" then restart Leksah, if that doesn't work you might need to rebuild system data.

I think I had problems getting this to work except when I re-installed Leksah and it asks you to add those settings for the first time.

EDIT: okay I just read you're using XP, this will be somewhere in your Docs & Settings directory, on windows 7 for me it's in C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Roaming\cabal

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a cabal folder under "c:\Documents and settings\username\Application Data", but it only contains a config file, no haskell source. In that config file, the remote-repo property specifies "hackage.haskell.org:http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive", while the remote-repo-cache property specifies a "packages" folder under the cabal folder. The packages folder isn´t there, but my guess is that it is supposed to contain the source for the packages. I will try to find out, if the ghc-pkg recache is supposed to create that folder.

Comment: Resolved. I am not sure how this happened, but after messing around a bit, mostly just reinstalling haskell platform and leksah a couple of times, I noticed that there now was a packages folder in the ....\Application Data\cabal folder. After reinstalling Leksah, doing a recache and pointing Leksah to the packages folder on first startup, Leksah started to update system metadata, and now I have a full system scope module browser. So, all is well, even if I am not sure when the packages folder got there. Thanks for the help.